# myFunction.init() is "not a function" - how can i start the jquery code?

Tags: jquery, call, init

i cannot find the right way to start the script. I have several variables, so the function when the document is ready, then the variable myFunction, and loadIMG, etc. and at the end of the code, the call to myFunction.init(), but Firebug tells me "myFunction.init() is not a function" . How could i start it the right way? 
Thanks for any help :

```
$(function () {  
    //...  
    var myFunction = (function() {   
        var init = function() {  
            loadIMG();     
        },  
        loadIMG = function() {  
            etc.  
        //...  
        //then at the end of the page :  
    })(); /* myFunction */  
    myFunction.init();  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat `myFunction` as a constructor, you need to do one of two things.

1. Return an object with the methods you want.

   ```
   var myFunction = (function() {   
       var init = function() {  
           loadIMG();     
       },  
       loadIMG = function() {  
           etc.  
       //...  
       return {
           "init": init
       };
   })();
   ```
2. Actually make a constructor and use the `new` keyword. Allocate any public methods/variables as properties on `this`.

   ```
   var myFunction = new (function() {   
       this.init = function() {  
           loadIMG();     
       };
       var loadIMG = function() {  
           etc.  
       //...
   })();
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the return worked just fine ! why do we need to specify a return? i think i'm a bit confused with that

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating the anonymous function since you are writing `(function () {})()` instead of just `function () {}`, is that a mistake? If not, does the anonymous function return a new function?. Check `typeof myFunction` to see if it is indeed `"function"`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access your function outside of the scope it's visible in. Since you've declared the myFunction variable INSIDE the $(function(){}) it is only visible in that scope.

If you want to access it at the point where you are trying to, you'll need to declare myFunction outside of the function as such:

```
var myFunction;
$(function () {
    //...
    myFunction = (function() {
...
```

Then you can refer to myFunction anywhere in the script.